# Computer that would last 100 years

Tags: desktop

Design a desktop computer system that would reasonably be expected to last for 100 years. Assume it will be used for 3 hours every day in this period (100,000 hours)

If some parts of the computer simply won't last that long, try and estimate how many spares might be needed to last the 100 years. For example, what type of monitor would last the longest before catastrophic failure? Would it last 100,000 hours? If not, how many would you need? Are there issues storing spare parts for long periods of time?

Assume the computer has about 1TB of data that you'd want to keep for the 100 year period. What backup strategy would you use?

Performance is not really an issue. Assume the machine will be used for running Office type applications.

If there are too many possible approaches to this to answer the question, then try and aim for the cheapest option you can think of.

Comment: I recommend [this computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus).

Comment: @Mark Get enough of those together and you've got the original server rack!

Comment: I recommend planning to stop upgrading to a new OS since you'll pretty much be locked in as to how much RAM, etc. you'll be able to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most all electronic devices have a MTBF (Mean Time Between Failure) specification.

You can use the spec. to find the highest MTBF, and then calculate how many you will need to cover 100 years.

Of course this is on average. Your best bet would be to exceed it as much as possible.

And whatever you do, DON'T drop it!